# Counting the amount of times several table names appear in a column of strings

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to count how many times several table names appear in the mysql.general_log table.

For example the `mysql.general_log` table the argument column would have values such as:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| argument                                                                     |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON'                                                |
| SELECT * FROM TABLEB WHERE val = 1 LIMIT 0, 1000                             |
| SHOW INDEX FROM 'DB1'.'TABLEB'                                               |
| DELETE FROM TABLEC WHERE val = 1                                             |
| UPDATE TABLEC SET val2 = 5 where val = 8                                     |
| DELETE FROM TABLEA WHERE val = 1                                             |
| DELETE FROM TABLED WHERE val = 1                                             |
| SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLED WHERE val = 1 LIMIT 0, 1000                      |
| DELETE FROM TABLEB WHERE val = 1                                             |
| SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLEB LIMIT 0, 1000                                    |
| UPDATE TABLEB SET city = 'NYC' WHERE val IN (2,6)                            |
| SELECT name FROM TABLEA WHERE val IN (2,3) LIMIT 0, 1000                     |
| SHOW INDEX FROM ''DB1.'TABLEA'                                               |
| INSERT INTO TABLEB VALUES(34)                                                |
| INSERT INTO TABLEA VALUES(34)                                                |
| INSERT INTO TABLEA VALUES(34)                                                |
| COMMIT                                                                       |
| SET GLOBAL general_log = 'OFF'                                               |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Then the goal is to have table that would show the counts for each table used

```
|TABLE NAME| COUNTS 
| TABLEA   |  5
| TABLEB   |  5
| TABLEC   |  2
| TABLED   |  1
```

So far this is the best solution I could come up with:

```
SELECT argument, COUNT (*) FROM mysql.general_log
    WHERE  argument LIKE '%TABLEA%'   OR
           argument LIKE '%TABLEB%'   OR
           argument LIKE '%TABLEC%'   OR
           argument LIKE '%TABLED%'
    GROUP BY argument ORDER BY TIMES ASC;
```

I've also though about maybe using `information_schema.TABLES` and selecting all rows where the `TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DB1';` to get the table names if that provides any clues to a solution.

Comment: For a reliable solution you would need an SQL parser. Otherwise you can't know if `TABLEA` is used in the FROM clause, as column prefix or just in a string. One way might be to execute `EXPLAIN` for every statement and extract the `table` column from the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slow and dirty version (very close to your own suggestion)

```
SELECT t.table_name, COUNT(l.argument)  
FROM information_schema.tables t 
LEFT JOIN mysql.general_log l 
  ON (l.argument REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]',t.table_name,'[[:>:]]') = 1)
WHERE t.table_schema='DB1' 
GROUP BY t.table_name;
```

e.g.

```
SELECT t.table_name, COUNT(l.argument)  
FROM information_schema.tables t 
LEFT JOIN mysql.general_log l 
  ON (l.argument REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]',t.table_name,'[[:>:]]') = 1)
WHERE t.table_schema='onemillion' 
GROUP BY t.table_name;
+---------------+-------------------+
| table_name    | COUNT(l.argument) |
+---------------+-------------------+
| citest        |                10 |
| invoice       |                 1 |
| invoice_box   |                 0 |
| invoice_myaes |                 1 |
| item          |                 1 |
| milltest      |                 2 |
| sbtest1       |                 3 |
| sbtest1_myaes |                 3 |
| sbtest2       |                 0 |
| sbtest2_myaes |                 0 |
| users         |                 6 |
| users_myaes   |                 3 |
+---------------+-------------------+
12 rows in set (0.23 sec)
```

As previously commented, this will just give you the log records which contain other identifiers that match your table names. It won't give you any clue as to the nature of the statements being run, so you wouldn't know if these log lines represented UPDATE, INSERT, SELECT etc., they'll all be lumped together. Depending on your requirement and the table names that might be good enough for a rough estimate.

A better way perhaps, if you have 5.6 or above, would be to use the `performance_schema` and query the `events_statements_history_long` table at appropriate intervals.

e.g.

```
SELECT t.table_name, event_name, COUNT(e.digest_text) 
FROM information_schema.tables t
LEFT JOIN performance_schema.events_statements_history_long e 
 ON (e.digest_text LIKE CONCAT('%`',t.table_name,'`%'))
WHERE t.table_schema = 'DB1' 
GROUP BY table_name, event_name;
```

The advantage here, aside from being able to group by statement type, is that mysql will normalize the queries and sling backticks around the table names so you can be certain of an exact match on the identifier. MySQL doesn't enable collection to this table by default so you might need to enable it within `setup_instruments` and adjust the amount of history to collect in your server startup with `--performance-schema-events-statements-history-long-size=a_suitably_large_number`.

[Full details on performance_schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/performance-schema.html)

Comment: Definitely an improvement, but sadly I only get counts of 0 for each row, but getting the table names is definitely an improvement, maybe using LOCATE to get the string location might help in some way?

Comment: @PatrickBornay Assume you're responding to the first example. Bit mystified that it's not working for you because I tested it locally before posting. mysql.general_log is stored in a file mysql/general_log.CSV in the mysql data directory, can you find any of the expected table names when you use grep on that file? I've updated the answer with a version which that's less susceptible to finding duplicates.

Comment: i'll try it again today, the tables i posted were just examples so its not exactly the same, but maybe i didnt use it correctly. If anything ill try it using the example tables and see if i get a different result. But yeah i did get the table names back and the arguments column in the general log table do have the table names show up. Also grep does work on it. Thanks for the follow up i,ll let you know how the testing goes.